Optimizing Memory and Performance for Immutable Chain Method Classes Handling Large NumPy Arrays
I'm working on a Python project that involves processing large numpy arrays using a chain of transformations. I've implemented two classes: Sample for individual arrays and SampleCollection for managing multiple Sample instances. The classes use immutable chain methods, returning new instances after each transformation.
Here's a simplified version of my implementation:
import numpy as np

class Sample:
    def __init__(self, array: np.ndarray) -> None:
        self.array = array
    
    def mean(self):
        new_array = self.array.mean(-1, keepdims=True)
        return Sample(new_array)
    
    def normalize(self):
        min_array = self.array.min(-1, keepdims=True)
        max_array = self.array.max(-1, keepdims=True)
        new_array = (self.array - min_array) / (max_array - min_array)
        return Sample(new_array)

    # Other transformation methods ...

class SampleCollection:
    def __init__(self, samples: list) -> None:
        self.samples = samples
    
    @property
    def arrays(self):
        return np.stack([sample.array for sample in self.samples])
    
    def mean(self):
        new_arrays = self.arrays.mean(-1, keepdims=True)
        return SampleCollection([Sample(array) for array in new_arrays])
    
    def normalize(self):
        min_arrays = self.arrays.min(-1, keepdims=True)
        max_arrays = self.arrays.max(-1, keepdims=True)
        new_arrays = (self.arrays - min_arrays) / (max_arrays - min_arrays)
        return SampleCollection([Sample(array) for array in new_arrays])

    # Other transformation methods ...

I'm dealing with large datasets, for example:
rand_arr = np.random.rand(3, 1000)
number_of_samples = 150_000
collection = SampleCollection([Sample(rand_arr) for _ in range(number_of_samples)])

I have two main concerns about the current implementation:

Memory usage: Creating new copies of objects for each transformation leads to significant memory consumption, especially with large arrays.
Performance: Instantiating new objects in list comprehensions for each transformation may be slow.

What are the best practices or design patterns to optimize memory usage and improve performance for this type of immutable chain method class?


Memory usage: Creating new copies of objects for each transformation leads to significant memory consumption, especially with large arrays.

This is the way Numpy works. Not to mention Numpy operations certainly already takes a major part of the execution time of your methods.
That being said, you can reduce the overhead of creating temporary arrays with compilation-based tools like Cython. This is what Scipy does. Numba and Numexpr can also help.
On top of that, you can compute the operation lazily by manipulating an abstract representation of your computation (typically with objects). This may require the end-user to call a function to explicitly perform the final computation. The alternative solution is to wrap types so end-user accesses perform the actual lazy computation. This is what CuPy does. Note that this can make the implementation significantly more complex.

Performance: Instantiating new objects in list comprehensions for each transformation may be slow.

I expect the creation of Numpy array to be the bottleneck, not the actual object creation.
While the usual solution is to perform vectorized Numpy operation, this is not always simple nor even possible. If the number of dimension of the array in each object is the same, the standard solution is to pack all arrays in a bigger one. If the shape is not the same, then you may need to reshape parts dynamically. For the complex cases, a module like Awkward may help.
Here again, modules like Cython and Numba can help to reduce the overheads. Cython can reduce the overhead of the loop but it will not fix the Numpy overhead (which are certainly the biggest issue). Numba can significantly reduce the Numpy overheads (thanks to JIT compilation and code specialization) though array allocation is still far from being cheap. For better performance, the best solution is just to perform the operation in a native language (or also possibly by calling malloc in Cython and using views). Note that the first call to Numba function can be expensive (due to the lazy JIT compilation). Scipy uses Cython to reduce such overheads though it is still not very fast yet (but significantly better than without Cython).
Simple/naive OOP composition can be eventually detrimental for performance (even in native languages). Indeed, designing a SampleCollection as a list of Sample force you to create many object, including expensive Numpy arrays. Instead, you can design SampleCollection as a big raw memory buffer virtually split in many sub-arrays (1D view which needs to be reshaped). In this case, a Sample is created only when needed and it contains only attributes useful to access the right sub-array (and possibly reshape it too). Note that this force the Sample and SampleCollection classes to be pretty dependent each other (while the Sample class can be used alone in your code) so this solution only works well if Samples cannot exist alone. If you need that, then you should create another class for orphan samples.
